# Autocompletion randomly activate when i press a checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I'm making a to-do list in javascript, but after i insert a element, when i try to press the checkbox i generate with the task, i got a random dropdown (from the input who was hidden (removeChild))

I try to recode some part but keep getting this problem :
- display: none
- hidden(true)

It can happen on Firefox but not on Chrome

```
function createInput(type, value = "", name =  "", placeholder = "", require = false)
{
    const input = document.createElement("input")
    input.setAttribute("type", type)
    input.setAttribute("style", "margin-right:10px")
    if (value !== "") {
        input.setAttribute("value", value)
    }
    if (name !== "") {
        input.setAttribute("id", name)
        input.setAttribute("name", name)
    }
    if (placeholder !== "") {
        input.setAttribute("placeholder", placeholder)
    }
    if (require) {
        input.setAttribute("required", "true")
    }
    return input
}
const addTaskElt = document.getElementById("add_task")
const formElt = document.getElementById("list_task")
const inputElt = createInput("text", "", "task", "Entrez votre tâche")
const submitElt = createInput("submit", "Ajouter")

const buttonElt = document.createElement("button")
buttonElt.textContent = "Ajouter une tâche"
addTaskElt.appendChild(buttonElt)

buttonElt.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    addTaskElt.removeChild(buttonElt)
    addTaskElt.appendChild(inputElt)
    addTaskElt.appendChild(submitElt)
    inputElt.focus()

    formElt.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const itemElt = document.createElement("span")
        const checkElt = createInput("checkbox")
        const taskElt = document.createElement("span")
        if (e.target.task.value !== "") {
            taskElt.textContent = e.target.task.value
            itemElt.classList.add("item")
            itemElt.appendChild(checkElt)
            itemElt.appendChild(taskElt)
            formElt.appendChild(itemElt)
            // Switch form and button
            inputElt.value = "" // clear input
            addTaskElt.removeChild(inputElt)
            addTaskElt.removeChild(submitElt)
            addTaskElt.appendChild(buttonElt)
        }


        // We can edit the task by clicking it
        taskElt.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const result = prompt("Modifier la tâche")
            if (result === null) {

            }
            else if (result === "") {
                formElt.removeChild(itemElt)
            }
            else {
                taskElt.textContent = result
            }
        })

        checkElt.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
            if (e.target.checked) { // if check, task done
                taskElt.setAttribute("style", "color:gray;text-decoration:line-through")
            }
            else {
                taskElt.setAttribute("style", "color:black")
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Can we see the function createInput? You may want to do a .setAttribute(“autocomplete”, “off”)  on your input element.

Comment: I added it on the post, yes it's working with it : i used it when i use removeChild then before using it again, i turn it to on. Thank you ! If someone knows why it happens, i will be happy too, really want to learn why it's happening !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment above, Im assuming .setAttribute(“autocomplete”, “off”) worked to solve your problem.

It would appear autocomplete is on by default on input fields, but I did not see a default case on mdn, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete. It does, however, state "The source of the suggested values is generally up to the browser". So if the browser thinks the items in the list are important to that input field then go ahead and show the related list.

Comment: Thank you, it's working for now ! Still trying to figure out why the autocomplete list is appearing from the top left corner of the web page without it.